# Is there a way to unpack a dictionary into an f-string **template**?

Tags: python, templates, f-string

With `.format` we can unpack a dictionary into a string template. That's the only thing I haven't found how to do with f-strings.
Is there a way to do it?

E.g. how to do this with f-strings?

```py
template = "my values: {number} {item}"
values = dict(number=1, item='box')

print(template.format(**values))
```

Edit:

I thought you can have f-string templates for undefined values with something like this, but it doesn't work either:

```py
template2 = "my values: {(number := None)} {(item := None)}" # values are immutable after defining
values = dict(number=1, item='box')

# how to unpack `values` into `template2`, is it possible?
```

I'm aware of the longer ways to do it, what I'm looking for is only whether it's possible to use unpacking. Cheers!!

Comment: Why do you want to use an f-string for this? I'm not sure it's possible without modifying the variable namespace, which is hacky. Either way, `str.format()` works perfectly fine, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm just curious to learn if it's possible because as I mentioned this is the only thing I haven't been able to do with f-strings that can do with `.format`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with these:

```
values = dict(number=1, item='box')
print(f"{values=}")
print(f"values= {values['number']} {values['item']}{values.get('missing')}")
```

which gets you:

```
values={'number': 1, 'item': 'box'}
values= 1 box None
```

Or do you want to declare your f-string **before** you've set up the dict and then plug in the dict?  Sorry, no can do, f-strings get evaluated right away, they are not really pre-defined templates.

##### Pre-defined templates hack

I've worked a lot with templates, usually the `%(foo)s` kind or else Jinja2 templates and have missed the capability to pass templates around, when using f-strings.

This below is a hack, but it does allow doing that, after a fashion.  Thought of doing that a while back, never tried it though.

```
def template_1(**values):
    number = values["number"]
    item = values["item"]
    missing = values.get("missing")    
    return f"values1= {number} {item} {missing}"

def template_2(**values):
    return f"values2= {values['number']} {values['item']} {values.get('missing')}"    

print(template_1(**values))

def do_it(t, **kwargs):
    return t(**kwargs)

print(do_it(template_2,missing=3, **values))
```

Output

```
values1= 1 box None
values2= 1 box 3
```

Comment: Yes, what I wanted is the second part: pre define it as a template and then fill the values. But I think you're right, they get evaluated right away and cannot be used as templates

Comment: @RaiderofthelostBBS slight update.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I am aware of with f-strings, but there are string templates:

```
from string import Template

template = Template("my values: $number $item")
values = dict(number=1, item='box')

print(template.substitute(**values)) # my values: 1 box
```